# Differentiate pinchs from counterpinchs with UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone

It's possible to differientate bettwen a pinch gesture and a counterpinch gessture with  UIPinchGestureRecognizer ?

And it's possible to know the angle bettwen the two fingers that perform the pinch using  UIPinchGestureRecognizer ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scale returned from the pinch will be less than one on a "zoom out" and greater than one on a "zoom in".  There is no way to get the angle between the two fingers from the UIPinchGestureRecognizer; for that you'd have to track the touches manually.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by angle, you can retrieve the CGPoint values for the pinch's touchpoints using the method 'locationOfTouch:(NSUInteger) inView:(UIView)' .  From there you should be able to calculate an angle (again depending on what you mean by angle).

And as pointed out already, scale greater than or less than 1 will tell you zoom out/in.